# Finding nodes in the perimeter of a circle, within the radius of a node in networkx graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I wanted to mark an area in a road network within a radius of a node. Then I wanted to know the nodes that reside in the perimeter. In simple words, I want to know when I am entering the circled area.

I have generated a subgraph using networkx, but still, I cannot figure out how to find the nodes in the perimeter.

Comment: Do you know the location of every node?  Calculate the distance from the center node to every node.  Find all the edges connecting nodes that less than the radius from the center to nodes further away than the radius.  These edges must cross the perimeter.

Comment: That is computationally costly for larger networks like Chicago. If I have a method to find the nodes in the perimeter it would be great. I have to do the same for multiple nodes in my algorithm. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How many nodes do you have?  If there several tens of thousands or more then searching through every node for the ones at the correct distance is going to be slow, especially if you are using an interpreted language such as python.

You will need some way to quickly exclude nodes that are "obviously" too far away to bother checking. This will work if your radius is small ( <10% ) of the range of node locations.

[image]

The usual way of doing this is by using a quadtree.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Comparing performance of quadtree and simple search through vector of points in finding neighbours of a point. If there are less than 100 points to search, the performance is similar, at less than a microsecond for each search. For more than 100 points, the advantage of a quadtree becomes significant.

[image]

The C++ xode for this is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/quadtree

I have used this code to assign the nearest riders to London ( England ) restaurants for a take out delivery company.  The application stacked orders ( scheduling algorithm ), assigned drivers ( quadtree ) and calculated driver's delivery routes ( travelling salesman algorithm ) for 5,000 restaurants generating 20,000 orders in 3 seconds after all data became available.

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear from my explanation. I need to find the shortest path from source to destination. The requirement is that path need to go through the radius of a single node. But source and destination can reside outside the radius. I'm planning to get the original shortest path and then find the nodes that hit the perimeter of the area. So I am looking for a way to find nodes in the perimeter. The rest of the algorithm is already optimised. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: You still have not answered my question!  How many nodes do you have?

Comment: 100000 nodes is the target. Currently processing 12000

Comment: OK, in that case I strongly reccomend using a quadtree to filter out the nodes that do not need to be considered.

Comment: As I said I am using compressed database to process network. But for individual area is generated from networkx subgraph. I was looking for a method to find nodes in the perimeter. I have no intention to change the data structure for the moment. Thank you